# angularJs directive to format date

Tags: angularjs, date, format

I want to have a functionality in angular which help to enter date and show it in proper format and don't allow invalid values in it. also able to show server returned '20140314T00:00:00Z' json string for date.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 4):

Angular.js already have date filter `{{20140314 | date}} //  Jan 1, 1970 9:35:40 AM`

[Angular Date Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: i have date value in ng-model and this gives me error.

Comment: I want something like this which do not allow alphabets. https://github.com/IgorMinar/directives-workshop/blob/master/src/05_ngmodelctrl_parse_format/exercise/solution/datefield.js

Answer (score 3):

This works for me,

```
   .directive('myDate', ['$timeout', '$filter', function ($timeout, $filter)
    {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',

            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl)
            {
                var dateFormat = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
                $ctrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue)
                {
                    //convert string input into moment data model
                    var pDate = Date.parse(viewValue);
                    if (isNaN(pDate) === false) {
                        return new Date(pDate);
                    }
                    return undefined;

                });
                $ctrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue)
                {
                    var pDate = Date.parse(modelValue);
                    if (isNaN(pDate) === false) {
                        return $filter('date')(new Date(pDate), dateFormat);
                    }
                    return undefined;
                });
                $element.on('blur', function ()
                {
                    var pDate = Date.parse($ctrl.$modelValue);
                    if (isNaN(pDate) === true) {
                        $ctrl.$setViewValue(null);
                        $ctrl.$render();
                    } else {
                        if ($element.val() !== $filter('date')(new Date(pDate), dateFormat)) {
                            $ctrl.$setViewValue($filter('date')(new Date(pDate), dateFormat));
                            $ctrl.$render();
                        }
                    }

                });
                $timeout(function ()
                {
                    $element.kendoDatePicker({

                        format: dateFormat
                    });

                });
            }
        };
    }])
```